# How to use Conversation state for unit testing a bot builder dialog?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, botframework

I am developing a multi lingual bot that uses LUIS for NLU conversation state to store the language preference.

```js
const { ComponentDialog, WaterfallDialog } = require("botbuilder-dialogs");
const { t } = require("../../utils/translations");

class HowAreYou extends ComponentDialog {
  constructor(id, localeProp) {
    super(id);
    this.localeProp = localeProp;
    this.initialDialogId = "mainDialog";

    this.addDialog(
      new WaterfallDialog(this.initialDialogId, [this.showHowAreYou.bind(this)])
    );
  }

  async showHowAreYou(step) {
    const locale = await this.localeProp.get(step.context);
    await step.context.sendActivity(t(locale, "how_are_you_response"));
    return await step.endDialog();
  }
}

exports.HowAreYou = HowAreYou;
```

This is the code for the unit test.

```js
const { DialogTestClient, DialogTestLogger } = require("botbuilder-testing");
const assert = require("assert");
const { HowAreYou } = require("../../../app/dialogs/small-talk/how-are-you");
const { SMALL_TALK } = require("../../../app/data/dialog-ids");

describe("How are you dialog", () => {
  it("Should respond with its status", async () => {
    const howAreYouClient = new DialogTestClient(
      SMALL_TALK.HOW_ARE_YOU,
      HowAreYou,
      undefined,
      [new DialogTestLogger()]
    );
    let reply = await howAreYouClient.sendActivity("How are you doing?");
    assert.strictEqual(reply.text, "Wonderful as always! Thanks for asking");
  });
});
```

When running the test with `npm test`, the test failed and throws this error:

```
> mocha test/**/*



  How are you dialog
    - User: Text = How are you doing?
    - -> ts: 11:40:28
    1) Should respond with its status


  0 passing (14ms)
  1 failing

  1) How are you dialog
       Should respond with its status:
     Error: DialogSet.add(): Invalid dialog being added.
      at DialogSet.add (node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/dialogSet.js:87:19)
```

In the main bot file constructor, I **added** the logic for **loading** all the bot dialogues and adding them to the **dialogSet**. How can I fix the issue in order simulate a test data.

Comment: This might be due to the package versioning [issue](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/issues/57). All of the BOTBUILDER packages should be the same version. Can you try checking if all the packages have the same version? Also, another option would be to delete the botbuilder-testing folder inside the project's node_modules folder and run `npm install botbuilder-testing`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting DialogSet.add(): Invalid dialog being added when testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440065/getting-dialogset-add-invalid-dialog-being-added-when-testing)

Comment: I had the same issue. First run npm update to make sure all of your packages are up to date (and double check package-lock.json to make sure all of the packages including within the other dependencies are the same version). In my case they were and I still got the same error. Other solution is as ranusharao suggested. Delete the botbuilder-testing folder directly and reinstall. That fixed it for me. See my related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440065/getting-dialogset-add-invalid-dialog-being-added-when-testing

Comment: I tried to remove the botbuilder-testing package and reinstall it again. Also, I removed the hole node_modules folder, but the same error persists. I do not think that the error is related to the package. May be I should be preparing all stuff required by the bot before launching that dialog ... LUIS, Storage, ConversationState, all inputs should be there in order to run the test with success!